# How to switch from Twitter API 1.0 to 1.1

Tags: api, twitter

Twitter API 1.0 doesn't need an access token. The following line returns a XML file:
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=neodev2010

*Result: **Valid XML***

Cause API 1.0 is deprecated we need to switch to API 1.1:
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=neodev2010

*Result: **Error: Bad Authentication data***

I just found examples for API 1.1 based on large PHP classes.
How is it possible to authentication via GET parameters?

**Which parameters are missing to get a valid response?**

- access_token=123
- access_secret=345
- oauth_access_token=678
- oauth_access_token_secret=910
- consumer_key=234

Answer (score 1):

You can't authenticate to Twitter via a simple GET request.  You need to use their OAuth system which involves passing a few pieces of information back and forth.

I strongly advise you to find a script or a library where someone has already implemented OAuth and build your application on that.  OAuth is not easy to implement, and there's no reason to write new OAuth implementations when there are so many available for free.

Answer (score 1):

REST API 1.1 only support 'json' format of output.

SO use following endpoint along with your authentication data

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=neodev2010

Comment: Try to execute it and you will see that is same error: Bad Data